# Inherit particle animation birth time in particle systems in 2.90-3.0?

Tags: animation

Basically, I have shape keys for rain drops, splats etc all done in shader mapping. Whenever I pick these animated objects as particles then animation starts globally meaning that on frame 1 all of the animations start simultaneously.

How to make these particles inherit their birth time? Are there other any options rather than installing Animation Nodes?

**upd**:
I have tiled drops and splats so the only option to animate I've found was to import image as plane then animate mapping to make a loop. I've used constant interpolation so it animates as a sequence. Then I wanted to add numerous splats so particle system was used which emits my animated planes without gravity. However all of planes have same looped animation which starts globally. Meaning that splat loop does not start on birth but keeps playing from frame 1

Comment: can you please explain a bit more, what you want to animate and how?

Comment: @Chris I have tiled drops and splats so the only option to animate I've found was to import image as plane then animate mapping to make a loop. I've used constant interpolation so it animates as a sequence. Then I wanted to add numerous splats so particle system was used which emits my animated planes without gravity. However all of planes have same looped animation which starts globally. Meaning that splat loop does not start on birth but keeps playing from frame 1

Comment: thank you ! Now i understood...sorry, i am slowly sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

you will hate the answer, but that's the only one i know:

make a collection for your movie-planes and render them as particles:

[image]

Copy and move your movie planes to that collection.

[image]

Change your startframe in the shader editor for each movie as you like:

[image]

Comment: oh, that means with 100 rain drops I will need to make 100 start frames :<

Comment: if you want 100 different start frames...yes. But i think our eyes are not that fast. So i think it is enough to make 5 with +20 start frame each. i think - i did not try. But with just copy & paste and change one value...even to make 20 particles is just 5 min task.

Comment: I've come up with another solution. Had to create a collection with 5 rain drops and 40-frame loops. Moved around animated part e.g in the beginning of the loop, in the middle etc. Now it looks a bit better but still repetitive